# How can I express mathematically that a set I is the index of another set N?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a set $N=\lbrace{3, 4, 1, 3, \ldots\rbrace}$ that is an infinite sequence of randomly generated integer numbers and another set $I=\lbrace{1,2,3,4,5,...\rbrace}$ that is a sequence of integers to be the index of the set $N$ in such way that $n_1=3$, $n_2=4$ and so on. How can I express mathematically in a formal way that $I$ is the indexes of the set $N$? Is correct to do something like $n:I\mapsto N$?

Comment: It looks right to me.

Comment: How can I express formaly that $i$ is a subscript of $n$ and that $i\in I$?

Comment: You can say $N=\{3,4,1,3,\dots\}=\{N_i, i\in I\}$.

Comment: This might be of help to you: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write "Let $(N_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of integers", and then write $N_i$ to refer to the $i$-th element of the sequence $N$.

Comment: Can I do something like $(n_i)_{i\in I}$ to $n_i$ refer to the $i$-th element of the sequence in set $N$? or the reference to the element needs to be $N_i$?

Comment: @Davi No, there's not really any convention of using a lowercase letter to refer to an element of your sequence. If it was a matrix you might write $a_{ij}$ for an element of $A$, but never with sequences. You can always just call your sequence $n$ to begin with, though.

Comment: @Jack M "family of integers" you mean the family of the integers numbers in $N$ or is this a term used for indexes?

Comment: @Davi The integers in $N$ are the family. The indices are the indices or the index set.

Comment: @Jack M I wrote something like that: "Let $N$ be the infinite sequence of randomly generated integer numbers and $I$ the set of natural numbers, where $(N_i)_{i\in I}$ are the elements of the sequence in $N$." Is this correct?

Comment: @Davi It's technically correct, but if you're indexing with the natural numbers $\mathbb N$ anyway, you should just have a sequence $(N_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$.

Answer (score 1):

The "indexed family" notation $(n_i)_{i\in I}$ looks good, and it's even clear its values are probably integers. In any case, the "thing" you're trying to identify is a function $I\to N$. It's correct, then, to write $n\colon I\to N$. When using "family" notation, subscripted elements are *values of the function*. Thus for all $i\in I$, $n(i) = n_i$. More awkwardly — for a given $i_0\in I$,
$$
(n_i)_{i\in I}(i_0) = n_{i_0}.
$$

Another notation, emphasizing the function itself:
$$i\mapsto n_i\colon I\to N.
$$
You can even give it a name:
$$
f\colon i\mapsto n_i\colon I\to N.
$$
Which you prefer depends on context. If the correspondence $i\mapsto n_i $ is just one of several maps $I\to N$ that you're considering (in the space of a proof or a talk), then you'll probably prefer the latter.

Comment: I need to state that the elements of another set $K$ is the predecessor element in set $N$. So $K=\lbrace{0,N_{i-1},N_{i-1},\ldots\rbrace}$ in such way that $N_1=K_2$ or in other words $N_i=K_{i+1}$, e.g., if $N=\lbrace{2, 3, 1, 2, 0\rbrace}$ then $K=\lbrace{0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0\rbrace}$. The first element in set $K$ is $0$. How can I state something like that?

Comment: Why not give these things their usual names? Is $N$ actually $\Bbb N_+$? And is $K=\Bbb N = \{0,1,2,3,...\}$? $I = \Bbb N$ too? It sounds like you want another sequence $(k_i)_{i\in \Bbb N}$ such that $k_0 = 0$ and $k_{i+1} = n_i$ for all $i>0$.